# Generating input data with Ethers for low level call to Uniswap Router

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, contract-invocation, uniswap

I'm trying to generate the input data necessary to execute a low level contract call to the Uniswap `SwapRouter.exactInput` method.

I've done the same for the `exactInputSingle` successfully but can't get the one for `exactInput` to work. I assume it has to do with how I add the `path` data, hoping someone might have a working example or some advice on what I'm doing wrong.

```
// https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol

struct ExactInputParams {
        bytes path;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
}

/// @notice Swaps `amountIn` of one token for as much as possible of another along the specified path
/// @param params The parameters necessary for the multi-hop swap, encoded as `ExactInputParams` in calldata
/// @return amountOut The amount of the received token

function exactInput(ExactInputParams calldata params) external payable returns (uint256 amountOut);
```

And I'm trying to generate the data for it in Ethers v6:

```
const exactInputMethodId = '0xc04b8d59'
const path = ethers.solidityPacked(['address', 'uint24', 'address'], [wethAddr, 500, usdcAddr])
const exactInputData = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
    ['bytes', 'address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'], 
    [path, recipient, deadline, amountIn, amountOutMinimum]
)
```

I have a smart contract that exposes a simple test function that executes a low level call with the provided data:

```
function testRawCall(address _address, bytes4 _methodId, bytes memory _data) public {
    (bool success,) = _address.call(abi.encodePacked(_methodId, _data));
    require(success, "Contract call failed");
}
```

In this case it always fails with the "Contract call failed" error. Unfortunately no more info what exactly goes wrong and where, I've double and triple checked all other input parameters and I do have the `exactInputSingle` call working with the same parameters, so I assume it is the way `path` is encoded.